Does availability group listener runs on both SQL Server nodes or does it run on a separate machine
Lets say I am setting up AlwaysOn Availability Groups and following are the nodes:
Primary
192.168.1.10
Secondary
192.168.1.11
I try to create a DNS entry for availability group listener called AvailabilityListener to which client applications will connect. My question is, which IP address shall I define for this listener? Will it be primary IP or secondary IP or some other machine IP where this listener will be running?

Listener is virtual machine and it needs it's own IP and port

If it is a separate machine, that means something needs to be installed on it like SQL Server listener software? I have seen many videos on AlwaysOn Availability Groups but none talks about what exactly it is.

Nope. It's virtual computer created during installation of AlwaysOn with the only task of routing requests to primary node.

Hmm....interesting. So, when we create a listener, it actually creates a virtual machine with that IP and name in Active Directory. This is also confirmed from this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717629/creating-listeners-with-sql-server-alwayson-suddenly-stopped-working


My question is, which IP address shall I define for this listener?

You'll need a new IP if you're using a traditional listener, or if utilizing a distributed network name (dnn) it'll use the local node IP.

Will it be primary IP or secondary IP or some other machine IP where this listener will be running?

Traditional listeners will always use the IP associated with the subnet on the primary replica. DNNs will both be reachable, regardless of the replica status which can be a cause of interoperability issues.
